# All events are not included in the TRC-20 Event Listener

Tags: node.js, tron, tronweb

The transaction I sent doesn't come in every time, and the error rate is about 90%.

```
const trc20ContractAddress = "TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t"； //mainnet USDT contract
let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(trc20ContractAddress);

//enventname is the name of the event of the contract
await contract && contract.Transfer().watch((err, event) => {
  if(err)
    return console.error('Error with "Message" event:', err);
 console.log('- Result:', event.result, '\n');
  console.groupEnd();
});
```